# ImageView.getWidth() return same value in landscape and portrait screen

Tags: android

I want to make my ImageView's size is rectangle shaped based on its width and it's done with overiding `onGlobalLayout()` and put `photo.getWidth()`. But it is only work in portrait screen, and no in landscape screen.

**Portrait is works fine :**

[image]

**In landscape, the image not rectangle shaped**

[image]

And this is the code :

**fragment_productdetail.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/noimage"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/noimage"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/noimage"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/noimage"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**FragmentProductDetail.java**

```
ivPhotos[0] = (ImageView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage0);
ivPhotos[1] = (ImageView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage1);
ivPhotos[2] = (ImageView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage2);
ivPhotos[3] = (ImageView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage3);

for (final ImageView photo : ivPhotos) {
    photo.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            photo.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            photo.getLayoutParams().height = photo.getWidth();
        }
    });
}
```

Then i try put `Log.i("zihad", ""+photo.getWidth());` inside onGlobalLayout() to get the width in landscape, then it gives me same value of width in portrait. So what should i do to make it works in portrait and landscape?

*sorry for bad english, i ask here also to improve my english

Comment: Sorry, But can you provide a visual representation of what you want to achieve and what have been rendered. This can help me edit the question and to provide with an answer.

Comment: ah sorry, i forgot

Comment: i've edit it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Tip:

I am not sure, if this is what you want. From what I assume, I think you might require a layout with Square ImageView. If you are trying to change the layout after rendering it, you should call `photo.requestLayout();` before setting its height.

An alternative solution would be to use a SquareImageView. To achieve this, just create a View which extends ImageView and set the height by overriding its onMeasure like this.

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {

 @Override
 public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
  super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
  int width = getMeasuredWidth();
  setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
}
```

Now in your layout, substitute ImageView for MyImageView(with complete package name).

Comment: can i use getWidth() instead of getMeasuredWidth()?

Comment: You can't. The getMeasuredWidth() is called before onLayout. So you can't call getWidth here.

Comment: i am afraid getMeasuredWidth() not give me the real width

Comment: Sorry for replying late. getMeasuredWidth() will be getting the width before the layout is applied. So incase, you change stuff in runtime then you might not get the real width,